# Drop Down List in dataTable without a submit button

Tags: jquery

The code below is a table that will display all data from database. I want to use drop down list to select the Status option. Is it possible to hold the selected option after just selecting an option in a dropdown list without submit button? If can, how to do it?

```
var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable({
            aaSorting: [],
            lengthChange: false,
            //processing: true,
            //serverSide: true,
            columns: [
                { title: "Assign To", data: "Task_AssignTo" },
                { title: "Customer", data: "Task_ContactName" },
                { title: "Company", data: "Task_ContactCompany" },
                { title: "Project", data: "Task_Project" },
                { title: "Tasks", data: "Task_Name" },
                { title: "Priority", data: "Task_Priority" },
                { title: "Due Date", data: "Task_DueDate" },
                { title: "Status", data: "Task_Status" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean catch the value after the drop down list changed? if so, I am using jQuery to do it.

first listening the event

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ddlId').change(function () { selectChange(this.id); });
});
```

define the function "selectChange"

```
function (id) {
    var selectedValue = $('#' + id + ' option:selected').val()
}
```

complete script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#ddlId').change(function () { selectChange(this.id); });
    });

    function (id) {
        var selectedValue = $('#' + id + ' option:selected').val();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I am using datatable, and not html table... I know how to do the ddl for html table, but not for datatable :)

Comment: Sorry I am misunderstanding what you are asking :(